# gwr fitting using package mgcv and R2Bayesx in R

Tags: r, bayesian, gam, mgcv

I want to compare GWR fittings produced between spgwr and mgcv, but I got a error with gam function of mgcv . Here is a  example :

```
require(spgwr)
require(mgcv)
require(R2BayesX)

data(columbus)
col.bw <- gwr.sel(crime ~ income + housing, data=columbus,verbose=F,
                  coords=cbind(columbus$x, columbus$y))
col.gauss <- gwr(crime ~ income + housing, data=columbus,
                 coords=cbind(columbus$x, columbus$y), 
                 bandwidth=col.bw, hatmatrix=TRUE)

#gwr fitting with Intercept
col.gam<-gam(crime ~s(x,y)+s(x,y)*income+s(x,y)*housing, data=columbus)#mgcv ERROR
b1<-bayesx(crime ~sx(x,y)+sx(x,y)*income+sx(x,y)*housing, data=columbus)#R2Bayesx ERROR
```

Question:

1. How to fit the same gwr using gam and bayesx function(the smooth functions of location )
2. How to control the parameters to be similiar as possible including optimal bandwidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **mgcv** error comes from the factor that you are specifying the "interactions" between the spatial smooth and variables `income` and `housing`. Read `?gam.models` for details on using `by` terms. I think for this you need

```
col.gam <- gam(crime ~s(x,y, k = 5) + s(x,y, by = income, k = 5) + 
               s(x,y, by = housing, k = 5), data=columbus)
```

In this example, as there are only 49 observations, you need to restrict the dimensions of the basis functions, which I do here with `k = 5`, but you should investigate whether you need to vary these a little, within the constraints of the data.

By the looks of the error from `bayesx`, you have the same issue of specifying the model incorrectly. I'm not familiar with `bayesx()`, but it looks like it uses the same `s()` function as supplied with **mgcv**, so the model specification should be the same as I show above.

As for 2. can you expand on what you mean here Comparable getween `gam()` and `bayesx()` or getting both or one of these comparable with the `spgwr()` model?

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I want to discrimimate varing effect about location between all models. Because GWR may perform spurious varying correlations especially in small sample(see P ez, A., S. Farber,D. Wheeler 2011), I want to explore variation of the estimated coefficients by other models under the similiar configuration and to discern the possible relationships.